# IsMenuKeyEvent: found no unichar data in event; retranslated without deadkeys to produc

Tags: r

I am using R (not rstudio) in MacBook
when hitting the tab key to complete the directory name, I get the following warning
"IsMenuKeyEvent: found no unichar data in event; retranslated without deadkeys to produce '"
Does anyone know what that means, and could I get rid of it ??

Comment: I get the same error, I believe it started when I upgraded to MacOS Monterey. Are you on Monterey as well? I'm on version 12.2 of MacOS, and version 4.1.2 of R.

Comment: Yes - same here - the trouble started right after the Monterey upgrade. R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)

Comment: Addendum - it might be that there are some general problems with unicode on Monterey: see e.g. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253452518 and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253435504